# How can I build a list of multiple regex matches in Rascal?

Tags: regex, rascal

I have a `str` value containing a fair amount of text, and I match it against a regex. The `str` contains multiple matches of the regex, but of course I only get the first.
How can I enumerate over the other matches, of better, how can I collect them into a `list[str]` ?
Example:

```
str text = "hello here how home";
```

Now I can do:

```
if (/<match:h+>/ := text) println(match);
```

which prints the first match: `hello`.
Now, instead, I'd love to collect all matches into a `list[str]`. Other languages provide the `g` flag for global matching. What's Rascal's idiom for this?

Comment: Please show the code, it will give us a clue of what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can iterate over a pattern until there are no new matches to be made.

```
for (/<match:h+>/ := "hello here how home") {
   println(match);
}
```

or

```
[ match | /<match:h+>/ := "hello here how home"]
```

the reverse is also true, if you want to know if there is at least one item in a list:

```
if (_ <- lst) {
   println("lst is not empty");
}
```

Read more on [Pattern Matching](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Concepts/PatternMatching/PatternMatching.html) and [Enumerators](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Comprehensions/Enumerator/Enumerator.html) in the tutor.

If you want to match the word you might have to change the regex: `/<word:h\w+>/`

Comment: To supply a working example: with `str text = "hello how help home";` followed by `println([match | /<match:h.+?>\b/ := text]);`, you will indeed get a list of matches: `["hello","how","help","home"]`. Thanks!